# What's the best way to publish a small anthology of poetry?

Tags: self-publishing, poetry, anthologies

As the title said I'm seeking advice for publishing a small anthology of poetry. I have 28 poems and may possibly be adding somewhere between 3-9 more (for a grand total of 31-37). I personally know this would end up being quite thin and small of a book.

I have a title page, acknowledgments, a table of contents (2 pages), and an about the author page. I have it divided into subgroups so I do also have title pages for each section which contain brief descriptions of what the section entails. In total I'll have somewhere between 44-50 pages including all that was mentioned above.

I would love to publish it and have a hard copy of the book but don't know how to go about the process. I want to for sure have a hard, physical copy that I could put on my own bookshelf at home. Although it would be great to sell some as well I don't expect to have a huge audience. What is the best recommended course of action?

I have been interested in writing my entire life but have never really gotten far enough along in the process until now to have something that I feel is worth publishing and potentially sharing with others. Thank you all so much for your time and effort. I hope I can be published soon!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Tommy.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  I removed the [tag:publishing] tag because it looked like you were asking about self-publishing.  If I'm wrong, please revise.

Comment: I wasn't sure which one made the most sense which is why I put both. Thank you for the help! Also I just finished the tour :)

Comment: Hi Tommy, this is a good question, but it has already been previously asked and answered here:  [Self publishing a collection of poems](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/19608/self-publishing-a-collection-of-poems).  See also, https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44328/publishing-poetry/45018#45018  and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/whats-next-when-it-comes-to-poems/34641#34641 for additional answers. My best advice to you is to do a chapbook, as detailed in the first linked question/answer.